# Preventing child Tap event from bubbling to parent ListView item using MVVM Interactions

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

Tapping the `StackPanel` in the following XAML will trigger both `MyCommand1` and `MyCommand2`:

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding SomeSource}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Grid>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand1}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                <StackPanel >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand2}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

How is it possible to make sure that only `MyCommand2` is triggered, while maintaining proper MVVM style?

Comment: try by setting some background color to stackpanel. But am not sure

Comment: how about the command's pram. can you handle the event args which comes from the command pram? so that it not fire for `Grid`

Comment: You have a Grid and inside you have an empty StackPanel. You are trying to catch Tap event but you ain't even displaying anything. How is tap event being triggered at all? What element is the original source of tab event when you ain't having elements inside StackPanel or Grid? I suggest you to change your design. Futhermore explain us more that is tap doing and where is it comming from?

Comment: @devhedgehog, this is just an example... If it really matters, I can set Width, Height, and Background on the StackPanel and on the Grid, so it will be visible to the user. But it is not the issue here. The issue is preventing of event bubbling to parent UI element...

Comment: you can handle the event by setting handled to true and it should stop bubbling up

Comment: But in that case I'll need to write an event handler, instead of using the Interaction.Triggers

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to write your own `EventTrigger` and inherit from 'System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger'. That results in the following class which you can then use in XAML for the command binding.

```
public class EventTriggerWithoutPropagation : System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger
{
    protected override void OnEvent(System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var routedEventArgs = eventArgs as RoutedEventArgs;
        if (routedEventArgs != null)
            routedEventArgs.Handled = true;

        base.OnEvent(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

If you're developing for Windows Phone cast to `GestureEventArgs` instead of `RoutedEventArgs` as the latter doesn't have the `Handled` property.